# Test Google Cloud Messaging Push notification through Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin

I have configured Google Cloud Messaging Demo App in Android Studio. It is configured and showing screen "You can now use gcmsender to send downstream messages to this app."

To Test this Google says

> When the sample application loads on your device, run the following
>   gradle command to send a notification to all devices:
>
> ./gradlew run -Pargs=""

Can Any one guide here where and how to use this gradle command :

> ./gradlew run -Pargs=""

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code for configuring Google Cloud Messaging, I am also trying to Configure GCM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the Terminal, simply click on the Terminal Option that you will see in the status bar at the bottom in Android Studio. It will launch up a Terminal window for you and the directory will be shown. You can now execute any Gradle tasks.
Eg: gradlew run -Pargs="your_message"

Comment: Hi @optimus, Thanks for your time. I tried this, but got this error in Android studio terminal "bash: gradlew: command not found"

Comment: I used complete command what google wrote, and its working.
"./gradlew run -Pargs="O its working"
Thanks

Comment: I am also trying this sample and every time I run the command I get HTTP error 401 and the message is not delivered to the device. Someone experiencing similar difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

Use Android studio's terminal (left bottom) and type command which is written on https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start?configured as it is, it will take time to download gradle services, till then you have to wait.